# NoClassDefFoundError: WebMvcConfigurer

Tags: java, spring, mockito

The error is thrown when running a test class for a RestController.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer

    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTypeExcludeFilter.<clinit>(WebMvcTypeExcludeFilter.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer.instantiateTypeExcludeFilter(TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer.instantiateTypeExcludeFilters(TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer.<init>(TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizerFactory.createContextCustomizer(TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizerFactory.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizerFactory.createContextCustomizer(TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizerFactory.java:51)
...
```

I added the following dependency to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

The code below (Class name and variables name have been simplified)

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureWebMvc
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
public class ControllerTest {

  @MockBean
  Service service;

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void some_test() throws Exception {
    Mockito.when(service.getSomething())
        .thenReturn(something);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/errors")).andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(something)
        .andDo(print());
  }
```

Various attempt at using different annotations do not solve the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have @RestController, you can ommit WebMVC dependency. Only with 'starter-web' and 'starter-test' will run succesfully.

```
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

My example implementation.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class BusinessPostControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    protected BusinessCreate businessCreate;

    protected Long createBusiness() throws Exception{

        BusinessCreateDto businessCreateDto = BusinessCreateDto.builder()
                .name(ContentGenerator.companyName())
                .build();

       return businessCreate.create(businessCreateDto).getResultId();
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void createValidBusiness() throws Exception{

        String url = "/system/business";
        BusinessCreateDto businessCreateDto = BusinessCreateDto.builder()
                .name(ContentGenerator.companyName())
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(
                post(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(
                        objectMapper.writeValueAsString(businessCreateDto)
                )
        ).andExpect(status().isCreated())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", containsString("success")))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result.id", notNullValue()))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.result.id", isA(Long.class), Long.class));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void createBusinessWithInvalidInputParameters() throws Exception{

        String url = "/system/business";
        BusinessCreateDto businessCreateDto = BusinessCreateDto.builder()
                .name(null)
                .build();

        mockMvc.perform(
                post(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(
                        objectMapper.writeValueAsString(businessCreateDto)
                )
        ).andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", containsString("error")));
    }

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void createBusinessWithoutBodyContent() throws Exception{

        String url = "/system/business";

        mockMvc.perform(
                post(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        ).andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", containsString("error")));
    }

}
```

regards